# Opening a wsl shell from another windows application

Tags: windows-10, bash, cmd.exe, console, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to configure Tower (git client) to launch a wsl bash shell. I've tried a whole bunch of things, but it seems this isn't intended.

[image]

What I tried:

```
command:     c:\windows\system32\wsl.exe
parameters:  bash -i

command:     c:\windows\system32\bash.exe
parameters:  -i

command:     c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe
parameters:  /c "bash -i"

command:     c:\windows\system32\bash.exe
parameters:  -i

command:     c:\WINDOWS\System32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe
parameters:  wsl bash -i

command:     cmd 
parameters:  /c start start bash -i

command:     C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe
parameters:  /c start start bash -i
```

All of these just pop-up a console window for a very short time and then return to Tower.

Most of these commands work from the explorer window...

[image: windows cmd]

Comment: Did you try any other open source free git client like GitHub desktop?

Comment: @Biswapriyo not sure how that would help. I simply want to launch a wsl bash shell directly from Tower. I already like and use Tower. I'm not looking for another git client replacement.

Comment: Looks like this may be an issue for x86 windows applications not picking up the Windows x64 Filesystem redirection (https://stackoverflow.com/a/41757861/736079)

Comment: Looks like https://github.com/goreliu/wsl-terminal is an option, though I'd like to not depend on a 3rd party tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To launch a 64-bit executable from a 32-bit process, like launching wsl.exe from Tower, you need to use the `sysnative` [filesystem redirector](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog64/file-system-redirector).

In this case, run: `%windir%\sysnative\wsl.exe`

You can test this by first launching a 32-bit version of Cmd by executing the following from the Run Dialog (<kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>): `%windir%\SysWoW64\cmd.exe`

Then, inside the Cmd instance, you can execute the following:

`%windir%\sysnative\wsl.exe`

You should now see 64-bit WSL running attached to the same Console instance:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this workaround does the trick:

```
command:    C:\WINDOWS\sysnative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
parameters: wsl bash
```

It launches a 64-bit PowerShell instance to then load Windows Subsystem for Linux.

See also:

- https://jessehouwing.net/git-tower-launch-wsl-bash/

[image]

---

Alternative:

[Another option I found is to use `wsl-terminal`](https://github.com/goreliu/wsl-terminal), but since that depends on a 3rd party terminal and a whole bunch of other dependencies, it'd rather not use it.